# button-click-hander needs reference to other html-control

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am writing a html-control. In the html-code there is only a 'div'-tag with a specific id. With the help of javascript and jquery I call a 'create'-function that creates dynamically some buttons and a canvas lying in the 'div'. Now if I click a button the click-eventhandler should modify some properties of the canvas.

The problem: How to find the canvas?

Do I have to go over the parent property (or siblings) of the button and search for a canvas? Has the button-element a 'tag'-property for random data? Or is there any better way?

Here is a sample code with two html-controls that should be independent of each other:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.myHtmlControl = function() {

            var btn = $('<button>B</button>');
            var c = $('<canvas/>');

            btn.button().click(function(e) {
               // change content of canvas lying in #ctrl1 if clicked button lies in #ctrl1
               // otherwice change content of canvas lying in #ctrl2
            });

            $(this).append(btn);
            $(this).append(c);
       };
    })(jQuery);

    $(function () {
        $('#ctrl1').myHtmlControl();
        $('#ctrl2').myHtmlControl();
    })
</script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div id='ctrl1' />
        <div id='ctrl2' />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remember it is very helpful if you post code -- often answers can then be clearer

Answer (score 0):

Just add an id to the canvas element as you create it.

Then you can search for it just like any other element with an id.

Comment: but what should I do if I want to use my html-control not only once in my html-document?

Comment: I don't see why that is a problem, just make it have the id once.

Answer (score 0):

So I just found a solution to my problem, maybe there are better ones...

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.myHtmlControl = function() {

            var btn = $('<button>B</button>');
            var c = $('<canvas/>');

            var t = $(this);
            t.X = 75;

            btn.button().click(function(e) {
                callX();
            });

            $(this).append(btn);
            $(this).append(c);

            function callX() {
                alert("ID: " + t.attr('id') + " X: " + t.X);
            }
       }
    })(jQuery);

    $(function () {
        $('#ctrl1').myHtmlControl();
        $('#ctrl2').myHtmlControl();
    })
</script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div id='ctrl1'>Ctrl1</div>
        <div id='ctrl2'>Ctrl2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But there is still a problem. The problem occurs in "$.fn.myHtmlControlKeydown()"-function where I would like to access the canvas and variable X belongig the the calling div.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.myHtmlControl = function() {

            var btn = $('<button>B</button>');
            var c = $('<canvas/>');

            var t = $(this);
            t.X = 75;

            btn.button().click(function(e) {
                callX();
            });

            $(this).append(btn);
            $(this).append(c);

            function callX() {
                alert("ID: " + t.attr('id') + " X: " + t.X);
            }
        }
        $.fn.myHtmlControlKeydown = function(e) {
            // access canvas and variable X from calling 'div'
        }
    })(jQuery);

    $(function () {
        $('#ctrl1').myHtmlControl();
        $('#ctrl2').myHtmlControl();
    })

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        $('#ctrl1').myHtmlControlKeydown(e);    // or $('#ctrl2').myHtmlControlKeydown(e);
    }); 
</script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div id='ctrl1'>Ctrl1</div>
        <div id='ctrl2'>Ctrl2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?